# What is arbitrary axis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I was reading 3D graphics programming book, the topic was about rotation.

I did not understand what "rotation about arbitrary axis" means and how it looks like

I have idea and visual of "rotation about cardinal axis" but the book does not even has any visual to help me visualize it. Can some one help me understand it with a visual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Arbitrary” means you may choose the axis of rotation any way you like. So simply choose any line in space, and then put a pin into your object along that line, and rotate the object around the pin.